# MinGW, _sleep()

Tags: c, mingw, sleep

Подскажите, какой заголовочник нужно подключить, чтобы при вызове функции **_sleep()** компилятор не ругался:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function '_sleep' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
```

Я использую **_sleep()**, потому что использование **Sleep()** в **MinGW** приводит к повреждению стека/кучи. Это проблема давно известна, так что мне совершенно точно необходимо использовать **_sleep()**.

Comment: Ну ругается себе, пусть ругается. Добавьте правильное обявление функции и все будет ок.

Comment: Проблема не решается. Вообще, прототип названной функции лежит в **stdlib.h**. И даже если указанный заголовочник подключен, компилятор все равно говорит, что функция неизвестна. Это очень странно. Меня это беспокоит потому, что однажды в похожей ситуации я уже оказывался. Не помню точно, в чем там было дело, но функция вызывалась без предварительного объявления. Это тысячу лет работало, но однажды переданный в функцию параметр **float** стал превращаться в **int**. Это классическое UB.

Comment: Я пытался найти описание этой проблемы со Sleep, но ничего не вижу

Comment: В `MinGW` TDM32 много чего нет, в декларациях. Но оно есть в базовых библиотеках win, которые он все равно линкует, по этому это и собирается. Выход, то что не задекларированно, дописывать руками, через `#if defined __MINGW32__`

Comment: И вообще то POSIX функция называется `sleep` - без подчеркивания :)